# JPA add new entity to collection, after transaction, the entity still has no id

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

```
    UserInfoEntity user = userRepository.findOne(1L);
    ActivityInfoEntity entity = new ActivityInfoEntity();
    entity.setUser(user);
    user.getActivities().add(entity);
    userRepository.save(user);
    TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization(new TransactionSynchronizationAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void afterCommit() {
            System.out.println(entity.getId());// null
            System.out.println(user.getActivities().size());// 1
        }
    });
```

Even after commit, the entity has no id, but add to collection create a new entity.

If I do `activityRepository.save(entity);` will add double to collection[HHH-6776](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6776).I need `entity.getId()` in this function to do something else.If I `return entity`, the returned `entity` will have an id, what's wrong ?

**EDIT**

`saveAndFlush` still null

[image]

Spring-boot 1.3.3

**EDIT**

The service is annotated with `@Transactional`.

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "activity_info")
@Where(clause = "is_del = 0")
public class ActivityInfoEntity{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
  @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "activity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  List<UserInfoEntity> users;
}


@org.hibernate.annotations.Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
@Entity
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Table(name = "user_info")
@Where(clause = "is_del = 0")
public class UserInfoEntity{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
  private ActivityInfoEntity activity;
}
```

**EDIT**

[HHH-6776](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6776) Hibernate inserts duplicates into @OneToMany collection

Comment: Try to flush after save

Comment: @Jens Still null, because after commit, the collection already contain an entity, the origin entity is not tracked, so there is no id.But I don't know why.

Comment: can you post your `ActivityInfoEntity`?

Comment: Turning the users collection into a set should fix the duplication on save problem by the way assuming you have a good hashcode implementation on the entities, but won't impact the apparent failure to cascade.

Comment: If I use set, every time I insert will check set first, I think this is not good.I use Spring AbstractEntity hascode and compare.

Comment: That will also happen with a list since list is ordered; if you want to avoid Hibernate checking anything you should use Collection instead of List, that way Hibernate will use a bag.

Comment: AFAIK,this list is unordered, because I don't use any OrderColumn, the underlying is a PersistentBag, and I confirmed that.

Comment: You are saving the User. User is an existing instance so `merge()` is called under the hood. A call to merge returns the merged object leaving the original unchanged. Therefore do `user = userRepository.save(user);`. Get the child entity from the merged instance and the ID should be set.

Comment: So I have to retrieve the list again for a single id, if list allowed multi value, this will not work,if I save child entity first, the merge will not create a new entity, so the entity's id will be set.

Comment: What exactly is it you are looking for? The call to save() returns the merged object. You can access this list in this which will contain the merged state.